# Question involving the application of Intermediate Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, continuity

I'm new to mathematical proofs, and I have just covered the Intermediate Value Theorem. I have tried to practice my understanding of the theorem, but I have encountered a question that I'm not sure how to approach.

> The question is:

Assume that $f$ and $g$ are continuous on the interval $[0,1]$ and $0 ≤ f(x) ≤ 1$ for all $x∈[0,1]$. Show that if $g(0) = 0$ and $g(1) = 1$, then there exists a $c\in[0,1]$ such that $f(c) = g(c)$.

> What I have tried doing:

Introducing another function like such $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$ and applying the theorem. However, I'm not sure if that is possible, or how I should go about doing it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seemed the question itself was not formulated well (a few words seemed to be missing). I've adjust the formulation of your question. I hope my adjustments are ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 1.** $f(0)=0$. In this case $f(0)=g(0)=0$, so there is nothing to prove.

**Case 2.** $f(1)=1$. In this case $f(1)=g(1)=1$, and so there is also nothing to prove.

**Case 3.** (The generic case). Suppose $f(0)\neq 0$ and $f(1)\neq 1$. Introduce the function $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ as you did. What can you say about the value $h(0)$? What about $h(1)$? Can you apply the intermediate value theorem?

Can you finish the proof yourself from here?

Comment: Thanks! Just to check my understanding, to complete the proof can we can just show that $h(0) >0$ and $h(1) < 1$ (using the IVT thm)?

Comment: Exactly! By those two conditions (and the continuity of $h$ on a closed interval, of course) you may conclude that the function $h$ is zero somewhere.

Comment: Doing cases is good and is helpful to be sure and I definitely encourage it.  But doesn't the IVT apply to closed intervals as well as open intervals?  If $h(x) = f(x)-g(x)$ then $h(0) = f(0) \ge 0$ and $h(1) = f(1)-1 \le 0$ so $h(0) \ge 0 \ge h(1)$ so we can apply the IVT to know there is a $c \in [0,1]$ so that $h(c) =0$, can't we?  Admittedly it's possible that $h(0)= 0 =h(1)$ of $h(0)=0>h(1)$ or $h(0)>0=h(1)$ and there is no $c: 0 < c < 1$ where $h(c)=0$, but that's not a show stopper, is it, because in those cases, it *is* acceptable for $c =0$ or $c=1$, isn't it?

Comment: I agree, it is not necessary to consider the first two case separately.

Answer (score 2):

> Introducing another function like such h(x)=f(x)−g(x) and applying the theorem.

That's *exactly* the right thing to do!

$h$ is continuous as $f, g$ are. And $h(0) = f(0)-g(0) = f(0) - 0=f(0)$  so $0 \le h(0) = f(0) \le 1$.  whereas $h(1) = f(1) -g(1) = f(1) - 1$.  Now $0 \le f(1)$ so $-1 \le f(1)-1= h(1) \le 0$.

Now IVT on $h$:  $h(0) \ge 0 \ge h(1)$ so there $c\in [0,1]$ so that $h(c) = 0$.  Which would mean $h(c) = f(c) - g(c) = 0$ and so $f(c)=g(c)$.